# Is it possible to search for images on Flickr using regular expressions?

Tags: flickr

I want to search for images on Flickr using regular expressions - e. g., `(Yahoo|Google) ("Image search"|"Web search")`. Does Flickr support any kind of regular expression searching (like Google Search)? Entering this query as-is seems to work on Google Image Search, but not on Flickr.

Comment: I mainly want to do this because Google Advanced Image Search doesn't seem to index all freely licensed Flickr images, so I need to use Flickr's advanced image search instead. For some reason, Google Image Search only allows me to search a tiny fraction of the freely licensed images on Flickr (via the "filter by license" option).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to search for images using regular expressions on Flickr, just like on Google Image search. Instead of typing `(Yahoo|Google) ("Image search"|"Web search")`, you would type `(Yahoo OR Google) ("Image search" OR "Web search")`. (Make sure that the "full text" option is selected instead of "tags only".)